# Flash vs JavaScript for interactive maps

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, dictionary, interactive, openlayers

I am developing a web application that is supposed to display land traffic in real time in any part of the world. For a couple months I've been developing it using JavaScript and OpenLayers (http://www.openlayers.org) framework.

Unfortunately, this solution appears to be inefficient. There are hundreds (200-300) of objects on the map that are updated every couple minutes. The sheer operation of refreshing and rendering them takes significant amount of time that makes the
application less usable (slow responsivity to user actions).

At the moment I am considering changing the technology. Adobe Flex seems to be the most reasonable solution. There is at least one application written in it that does similar things to mine (http://casper.frontier.nl/).

However, I have a couple of concerns regarding Flex:

- can it be easily integrated with the
  HTML/CSS/JavaScript based part of the
  application (for example, the
  graphical interface should be
  coherent when it comes to styles and
  colors)?
- I get an impression that
  with latest browsers (mainly Chrome
  9.0) JavaScript and CSS becoming more efficient. What are the chances that
  in a couple of months JavaScript+CSS
  will make it possible to implement
  efficient, flash-like rich internet
  application? (A note is needed here:
  famous Canvas tag is not a solution
  for my problem, at least not for now.
  Rendering objects on map with canvas
  proved to be less efficient than with
  traditional SVG because the size of
  the canvas is really big - a whole
  browser window)
- What are the chances
  that Flash technology will be
  abandoned (Apple policy, HTML5
  growing support etc.) in
  not-so-near-future (a couple of
  years)?
- There is a possibility that my client would like to view this application on mobile devices, including iPhone.
- Any other solution for web-based interactive maps?

Can anybody address these issues?

Comment: Are you re-rendering the whole page every time a single object changes? You probably want to re-render at periodic intervals and if possible only re-render the part that has changed. Note also that canvas has transparency and you could stack multiple canvas objects that render different layers/parts of the map (and only change the ones that change).

Comment: I've used Google Maps JavaScript API + a custom canvas tile layer (see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/59a52aecec860e75/d27bf90d5f71d392) and [here](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/maps/gridmark)) to draw maps with 10k+ markers, _really quickly_. Perhaps you just need to rethink your particular approach rather than totally rewriting your maps.

Comment: @kanaka - I only rerender single object when this particular object changes. I do not know much about Canvas tag but as I wrote in the question it appears to be less effective than SVG due to the canvas size
@Matt - I'm afraid this kind of solution is not good for my problem. I have to update every object (marker) independently and make it responsive to various actions (clicking, selecting, highlighting, hiding/filtering). In examples you gave markers are generated on the server-side and cannot be manipulated by user.

Comment: @Matt - you may disregard the above comment addressed to you. I admit I did not take a full deep look into the solution you gave (grid of canvas elements) when writing them. It really does look promising and worth considering. Thanks!

Comment: @gregorej: would you like me to post the comment as answer?

Comment: @Matt: definitely. I think this solution is worth spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Lazy comment repost:

I've used Google Maps JavaScript API + a custom canvas tile layer (see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/59a52aecec860e75/d27bf90d5f71d392?pli=1) and [here](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/maps/gridmark)) to draw maps with 10k+ markers, *really quickly*. Perhaps you just need to rethink your particular approach rather than totally rewriting your maps.

Comment: After a few months of designing and implementing I can say that this solution worked. Indeed, the problem was in JavaScript implementation that turned out to be inefficient. The solution with Canvas grid markers proved to be very useful. I have managed to display literally thousands of objects at the same moment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's good to know that this solution is viable for others.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript running on a modern browser (say, IE7 or later) should easily be able to handle 200 or 300 object updates every few minutes.  Granted, if you want to do all 300 updates at the same time, things might get a little slow.  But if those updates occur spread out over that period, then you shouldn't have any trouble.

There are Asteroids games and 3D shooters written in JavaScript and that are very playable.  They do dozens of updates per second.

I would suspect your framework (I know nothing about OpenLayers) or the way in which you're doing the updates before I suspected the platform.

My experience with Flash has been less that positive.  Although it will interoperate with JavaScript, there are some strange edge cases that will trip you up.  And my experience is that it's almost impossible not to trip over those edge cases unless what you're doing is truly trivial.  And, of course, the lack of Flash support on the iPad and iPhone will make supporting those platforms impossible.

I think it's unlikely that Flash will be *abandoned* any time soon, as there are too many customers who continue to believe the silly notion that Flash is the way to build interactive Web apps.  Although that was almost certainly true four years ago, browsers, computers, and JavaScript techniques have advanced to the point that the only use I currently have for Flash is to play video.  And that use will go away in the next few years when HTML5 video becomes more prevalent.  With Google's WebM video format and the expected high-quality tools to build WebM, Flash becomes almost irrelevant as a movie player, except for older content.

My advice would be to take a long hard look at your current implementation, study some other JavaScript applications that do frequent updates, and determine if it's really the platform rather than the way you're using it that is causing your performance problem.

Comment: Could you give some more information about those edge cases? Do they concern the problem of integration with CSS/HTML-based application?

Answer (score 0):

No idea how many objects you can manage and update in js, but in my company (flashmaps.com) we have built flash-based maps handling many thousands of objects. The key issue in many cases in fact is that the map is completely overlapped by the markers. We use to recommend filtering the markers in those cases. We have a huge experience in building flash/flex-based maps, so on't hesitate to ask me any question on that.

By the way, I don't think Flash will get out of use soon. Apple's strategy on controlling iPhone/iPad apps (the real reason behind Flash banning) is causing a lot of trouble to web developers, that need to create specific versions of their websites for these devices, it's crazy. But I'm sure Apple will permit Flash, someday... Probably when many other tablets hit the streets supporting Flash. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome thing about MVC architecture is as long as you keep your domain logic separate from your business logic and UI, then it's relatively easy to create platform specific apps that access the same data.  For example, you could build the same UI to run in the web browser (via html/javascript or flash player), on the desktop (via Air), and on an iPhone/iPad (via iOS) that all connect to the same server-side scripts.  It's all a matter of personal choice which platform you choose.  If a platform happens to fall out of fashion in the future, then you simply create a new UI on another platform.